# finding the maximum of $a$

Tags: inequality

$5ab-(a+b)=a^2b+ab^2$. Find maximum $a$.

Can anyone tell me how to find the maximum of $a$? When I saw these kind of inequality, the first thing I usually think about is completing the square but I dont see anyway that completing the square. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There is some context missing. Is the maximum of $a$ the maximal possible value of $a$ wrt $b$? I need more information.

Comment: um I think we want to find the maximum value of a. Thank you for the notice.

Comment: in this mode , a can take any value as b changes, so the answer could be infinity...

Comment: maximum of a can be defined if maximum  of b is given @alexzhang

Comment: RHS is $(1+b/a)a^2b=(a+b)ab$ LHS is $(3a-1)b-a=(3b-1)a-b= 3ab-(a+b)=(3-{3ab\over a+b})ab$  so for them to equal: $a+b = 3-{3ab\over a+b}$  which leads to things like $({a+b})^2=3(a+b)-3ab$.

Answer (score 1):

There are no maxima for $a$

Solve for $a$. You get

$a= \dfrac{-b^2+3 b-1+\sqrt{b^4-6 b^3+7 b^2-6 b+1}}{2 b} $

$a=\dfrac{-b^2+3 b-1-\sqrt{b^4-6 b^3+7 b^2-6 b+1}}{2 b}$

In both cases $\lim_{b\to 0} \, a=\infty$

Comment: would the answer change if the equation become $5ab−(a+b)=a^2b+ab^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $b\rightarrow-\infty$ and $b+\frac{1}{b}=2u$.

Hence, $a^2+(2u-3)a+1=0$, which says that there is $a\rightarrow+\infty$ for which the condition holds.

We got the answer:

The maximum does not exist.